# MatFormFieldModule / MatLegacyFormFieldModule Conflict without MatInputFieldModule import

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have to use Material Legacy Modules in a client Project.

Now i removed all occurences of both `MatFormFieldModule` and `MatInputFieldModule` with `MatLegacyFormFieldModule` and `MatLegacyInputFieldModule`. Still i get this Error:

```
NG0300: Multiple components match node with tagname mat-form-field: MatLegacyFormField and MatFormField
```

I searched all my Code.
There is no occurence of `MatInputFieldModule`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to migrate all form-related modules to the new version in your app module. This includes modules like `MatLegacySelectModule` and `MatLegacyInputModule`. Otherwise, `MatLegacyFormFieldModule` is still a transitive dependency in your application, even if you don't directly use it.